# Count the Contacts in the related list of Account and display the Contact count on Account Custom Field

Tags: trigger

I have Written Following Trigger but getting an Error.

```
trigger CountContact on Account (after insert, after update) {

List<Account> acc1 = new List<Account>();

if (Trigger.isInsert)
{
    for(Account acc : Trigger.New)
    { 
             List<AggregateResult>  cnt= [SELECT COUNT(Id) countTask FROM CONTACT WHERE Contact.AccountId =: acc.id];  
             Integer tskCount = (Integer)cnt[0].get('countTask'); 
             acc.Count_Contact__c = tskCount;
             acc1 .add(acc);
    }
}


if (Trigger.isUpdate)
{
    for(Account accN : Trigger.Old)
    {
        List<AggregateResult>  cnt= [SELECT COUNT(Id) countTask FROM CONTACT     WHERE Contact.AccountId =: accN.id];  
        Integer tskCount = (Integer)cnt[0].get('countTask'); 
        accN.Count_Contact__c = tskCount;
        acc1.add(accN);
     }
}
update acc1;
}
```

**Error is :**

> System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.CountContact: line 11, column 1

Comment: You need to write a trigger on Contact object, instead of Account object. Also need to consider, insert and delete event of Contact.

Comment: Also need to consider undelete event, as user can try to undelete record.

Comment: If i created the Trigger on Contact instead of Account, how i will be able to count number of contacts related to a particular Account. Because that count i want in my Accounts Custom Field called Count_Contact__c.

Comment: Whenever Contact is inserted (After insert event), you need to query all the Contacts associated with the AccountId field of the inserted Contact. And then need to update the respective Account record with the new Count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write the Trigger on Contact, because if a new Contact is created or deleted, the change in count must be reflected in the Parent Account.

You can try out this:

```
trigger CountContactOnAccount on Contact (after INSERT, after UPDATE, after DELETE ) {
Set <Id> accountIds = new Set <Id>();
List <Account> lstAccountsToUpdate = new List <Account>();
 if(Trigger.isInsert){
    for(Contact con:trigger.new){
        accountIds.add(con.accountID);
    }
}
if(Trigger.isUpdate|| Trigger.isDelete){
    for(Contact con:trigger.old){
        accountIds.add(con.accountID);
    }
}

for(Account acc:[SELECT Id,Name,Count_Contact__c,(Select Id from Contacts) from Account where Id IN: accountIds]){
    Account accObj = new Account ();
    accObj.Id = acc.Id;
    accObj.Count_Contact__c = acc.Contacts.size();
    lstAccountsToUpdate.add(accObj);
}

UPDATE lstAccountsToUpdate;
```

}

Comment: You should also add `after UNDELETE` to the list of Trigger actions.

Comment: Thanx its really helpfull. It sorted out my issue..

Comment: @AmolJadhav You should also consider `after UNDELETE` because if somebody undeletes a Contact this will affect your count.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that I think you should consider to change/do.

**1.Your logic should be** - 'Every time a new contact is Inserted or Updated or Deleted or UnDeleted, you should go to that contact's parent Account record and calculate all the contact records within this account (including newly inserted/Updated/deleted/UnDeleted contact)' Right ?

**Conclusion** -

a.The trigger should be written on 'Contact' Object not 'Account'.
b. In your query I see that there is a field naming countTask present in contact object (that you must have created in there) , but that is not required. (reread the logic, if any doubt).

**2.Now about the Error that you are getting**

> Your records are already locked after insert and that is why this
> error is occurring. :)

**Explanation :**
See in the code that you have written here, you are performing logic on account records *AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE* , that is the records are already inserted into Database but are not committed (until it clears all the logic under all the triggers written for 'After Insert/Update/Delete' on this object and *until then THE RECORDS ARE LOCKED FOR ANY CHANGES* ).

**Solution to this error**
*Change the event* of trigger *from 'AFTER* INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE' *to 'BEFORE* INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE' and the bug will get fixed. :)

Comment: **1.** *not 'After update' as the number of contact within a parent account will not change on updating a contact* - I disagree. If you update `Account` field on contact, the number of contacts linked to that account will change. **2.** *Change the event of trigger from 'AFTER INSERT/UPDATE' to 'BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE' and the bug will get fixed. :)* - no it won't. Well, it will, but that will cause another error. `Id` in a `before insert` trigger is `null` and OP is querying based on it

Comment: @Novarg Right :).

Let me make the change right away . :) 
Thank you for bringing this what I missed to ponder.

Comment: You should also add `UNDELETE` to the Trigger actions that will cause recalculation.  Also this Trigger should be an AFTER on Contact since OP is updating the Account.

Comment: @DougB does your comment refer to what I posted ?

Comment: Yes.  You stated in your Solution to change to `BEFORE` and `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`.  OP should also consider `UNDELETE` as this will change the count also.  Finally it should be an `AFTER` Trigger since OP is wanting to update Account.

Comment: Yes an Undelete is also required. You are right on that :) . Let me make the changes right away !
Also , my stating to use Before was error Specific ! and that was not a part of answer, so I keep that as it is. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a trigger on Contact rather than Account:

- On insert you should simply increment that custom field
- On delete you should decrement it
- On update you should decrement it from the old account and increment on the new one

Here's a tiny piece of code for the insert:

```
Map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Count_Contact__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :yourListOfAccountIdsThatYouShouldCreate]);
for (Contact c : contactList) {
    accMap.get(c.AccountId).Count_Contact__c++;
}
update accMap;
```

Similarly, you can write a method for delete and update.

**NOTE**: make sure that there is a value in Count_Contact__c, otherwise you will most probably get a `NullPointerException`.

---

And now a few words about your code:

1. Never put a query inside a loop. You will hit governor limits before you can say "WTF?"
2. *System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.CountContact* means that you can not modify this record anymore. If you want to modify it, use `before` triggers or make a copy of desired record(s) and then update it. But you can not change anything in `Trigger.new` in an `after` event
3. Your insert and update parts do exactly same thing, remove one of them. Duplicate code should be avoided at all costs, that will make maintaining a lot easier
4. Also, I don't think that an account will have any contacts linked to it after you create it, so your `after insert` doesn't actually do anything
5. Did I already mention governor limits and queries inside loops?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that may help

```
trigger NumberOfContacts on Contact (after insert, after delete, after undelete) {


    set<id> accIds = new Set<id>();
    set<id> oldaccIds = new Set<id>();
    List<id> conIds = new List<id>();
    List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>(); 
    List<Account> oldAccountList = new List<Account>(); 
    Integer count = 0;
    if ((trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUndelete) && trigger.isAfter) {
        for ( Contact con : trigger.New) {
            if (con.AccountID != null) {
                accIds.add(con.AccountID);
                conIds.add(con.Id);
            }
        }
        accountList = NumberOfContactsTriggerHandler.getAcocuntDetails(accIds, conIds);
    }


    if (trigger.isDelete && trigger.isAfter) {
        for (Contact con : trigger.Old) {
            if (con.AccountID != null) {
                accIds.add(con.AccountID);
                conIds.add(con.Id);
            }
        }
        accountList = NumberOfContactsTriggerHandler.getAcocuntDetails(accIds, conIds);
    }
NumberOfContactsTriggerHandler.updateNumberOfContactLinked(accountList);
}
```

---

```
public class NumberOfContactsTriggerHandler {

    List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();

    public static List<Account> getAcocuntDetails(set<id> accountSet, List<id> contactList ) {
        return [SELECT ID, No_of_Contacts_Linked__c , (SELECT ID FROM Contacts where id IN :contactList) contacts FROM Account where id in :accountSet];

    }

    public static void updateNumberOfContactLinked(List<Account> accList) {
        for (Account act : accList) {
            integer contactSize = 0;
            System.debug('acclist' + acclist);
            if (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUndelete) {
                System.debug('acclist' + acclist);
                System.debug('Contacts from Trigger.new' + act.contacts);
                contactSize += act.contacts.size();
                System.debug('act' + act);
                act.No_of_Contacts_Linked__c += contactSize ;
            }
            if (trigger.isDelete) {
                System.debug('acclist' + acclist);
                contactSize += act.contacts.size();
                System.debug('acclist' + act);
                act.No_of_Contacts_Linked__c -= contactSize ;
            }
        }

        System.debug('acclist' + acclist);
        update accList;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me there can be three cases when we update a contact :

1. previously accountId was null but then some value is updated
2. previously accountId had some value but then it is updated to null
3. the accountId is changed i.e periviously some othet value and now
   other

keeping this in mind I wrote this code :

```
 trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update , after delete){
         ContactTriggerHandler.countAllContactOfAccount(trigger.new,trigger.old,trigger.oldMap);
    }
```

and in ContactTriggerHandler these two methods

```
public static void countAllContactOfAccount(List newContacts,List oldContacts,MapoldMap){
    if(trigger.isAfter){
        List accounts = new List();
        if(trigger.isInsert){
            Set accIds = new Set();
            for(Contact con: newContacts){
                 if(con.AccountId != null)
                 accIds.add(con.AccountId);
             }
             accounts = updateAccounts(accIds);
        }
       if(trigger.isUpdate){
            Set accIds = new Set();
            for(Contact con: newContacts){
                if(oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId != con.AccountId){
                     if(con.AccountId == null){
                          accIds.add(oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId);
                     }else if(con.AccountId != null && oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId == null){
                          accIds.add(con.AccountId);
                     }else {
                          accIds.add(oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId);
                          accIds.add(con.AccountId);
                     }
                 }
                 accounts = updateAccounts(accIds);
            }
       }
       if(trigger.isDelete){
             Set accIds = new Set();
             for(Contact con: oldContacts){
                 if(con.AccountId != null)
                 accIds.add(con.AccountId);
             }
             accounts = updateAccounts(accIds);
        }

       update accounts;
      }
}

private static List updateAccounts(Set accIds){
     List accounts = [Select id, (Select id from Contacts) from Account where id in : accIds];
     for(Account acc: accounts){
          acc.Total_Contacts_Count__c = acc.Contacts.size();
     }
     return accounts;
}
```

Comment: This does appear to handle the main cases as well as the primary edge case that most people miss (setting the count to 0 when an Account loses its final Contacts). The `acc.Contacts.size()` will fail if there are more than 200 Contacts on a single Account though. One other thing to take into consideration is that the subquery consumes one additional row _per contact_ from the query rows governor limit. If that's an issue, then using `[SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accIds GROUP BY AccountId]` would be a better approach.

Answer (score -1):

Trigger should be written on contact object.
The below code is working for all listed operations:

1. Inserting Contact with an Account
2. Updating/Switching Accounts on Contacts ( this will update the count
   on both the Accounts )
3. Removing Account from Contact
4. Deleting Contact
5. Undeleting Contact

   ```
   trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert,after update, after delete, after undelete) {
   if(Trigger.isAfter) {
       Map<Id,List<Contact>> MapOfActIdandConList = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
       List<Account> accountToBeUpdate = new List<Account>();
       Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();

       if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete || Trigger.isUpdate) {
           for(Contact contNew : Trigger.New) {
               if(contNew.AccountId != null) {
                   AccountIds.add(contNew.AccountId);
               }
           }
       }

       if(Trigger.isDelete || Trigger.IsUpdate) {
           for(Contact contOld : Trigger.Old) {
               if(contOld.AccountId != null) {
                   AccountIds.add(contOld.AccountId);
               }
           }
       }

       if(!AccountIds.isEmpty()) {
           for(Contact ct : [Select Id,AccountId from Contact where AccountId IN :AccountIds]) {
               if(!MapOfActIdandConList.containsKey(ct.AccountId)) {
                   MapOfActIdandConList.put(ct.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
               }
               MapOfActIdandConList.get(ct.AccountId).add(ct);
           }

       }

       for( Id actId : MapOfActIdandConList.keySet()) {
           Account act = new Account();
           act.Id = actId;
           act.Count_Contact__c = MapOfActIdandConList.get(actId).size();
           accountToBeUpdate.add(act);
       }

       if(!accountToBeUpdate.isEmpty()) {
           update accountToBeUpdate;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -3):

Trigger Controller:

```
public class CountContactsOnAccountController{
    // Method to update the count of contacts on an account
    public static void updateContactCount(List<Contact>Contacts){
        
        //Storing Set of AccountIds to be updated
        
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        
        for(Contact cntcs: contacts){
            
            if(cntcs.AccountId != null){
                accountIds.add(cntcs.AccountId);
            }
            
        }
               
        List<Account> accList = [Select Number_of_Contacts__c, (select id from contacts) from Account where id in: accountIds];
        List<Account> accUpdate = new List<Account>();
        
        for(Account acc: accList){ 
            acc.Number_of_Contacts__c = acc.contacts.size();
            accUpdate.add(acc);
        }
        update accUpdate;                   
    }
}
```

```
trigger CountContactsOnAccountTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    //List<Contact> contacts = Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new;
    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isUndelete) {
            CountContactsOnAccountController.updateContactCount(Trigger.new);
        }
        if (Trigger.isDelete || Trigger.isUpdate) {
            CountContactsOnAccountController.updateContactCount(Trigger.old);
        }
    }
}
```

Check this video for proper explanation: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8-2ymkTbOM`

Comment: Code dumps make for poor answers, and this site isn't a place for you to promote your youtube channel. The explanation is as important as the solution itself, and the explanation should be here, on this site.

Comment: That aside, this does look like a reasonable approach. `acc.contacts.size()` will fail if there are more than about 200 Contacts related to a single Account (not likely an issue, but something to be aware of and plan for). This also doesn't handle the case where a Contact moves from one Account to another Account (the count on the Contact's old Account would not be updated). There's also an edge case where the count on the Account is not updated when all of the remaining Contacts are deleted at once (which in most cases means the Account would always be left with a count of 1 or 2 or so).